# Copy file to LibreOffice Calc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libreoffice-calc

I am tired of copying and pasting files in linux from file to LibreOffice. Is there a command that would allow me to copy a file to LibreOffice Calc file, deliminated by spaces, and where I could name the sheet?

I would want to do this form many, so I would want to open 1 workbook, copy and paste data from a file using command, name the worksheet, and then repeat in same workbook.

My directory is set up like:

Silicon/PKA1/timestep_size/v_0.001/

In this directory, there is a file called coordination.txt that I want to basically have in a LibreOffice Calc with sheet name PKA1

This goes from PKA1 to PKA24

So I want a code that will take coordination.txt from all of these subfolders and paste (deliminated by spaces) to a Libreoffice calc worksheet on 24 different worksheets for each PKA. So PKA1 will have a worksheet called PKA1 with coordination.txt pasted on it.

Comment: What are you pasting into calc, the entire file contents? Can you just open the file with calc, or is that where you're doing the copy & pasting, from one calc window to another?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  What is the source and nature of the files?

Comment: I have 24 files in 24 subdirectories. I was wanting to quickly copy and paste them to the calc document, without having to do it by hand. Each subdirectory has a file that would be copied a specific sheet

Comment: What kind of files?  What is the source?  Are these Calc files?  CSV data?  Text from logs?  How are they identified (every file in certain directories, a list)?  Where would the worksheet names come from?  Are you talking about directly inserting raw file contents or converting something into Calc content?

Comment: I edited question. I think I have everything now that explains what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Well, to have `find` dig through all the folders down from the current one (change `.` to any folder) and open each coordination.txt file in Calc:

```
find . -type f -name coordination.txt -print0 | xargs -0 libreoffice --calc
```

There are more options to `libreoffice`, see `man libreoffice`.

Or you could use [odfpy 1.3.4 - Python API and tools to manipulate OpenDocument files](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odfpy) and write a python script to *"Create OpenDocument spreadsheet from comma separated values"* for example.

And/Or you could have Calc [Start a macro when file is open](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=34914) or write a [Calc import txt script](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=10331).